# Can not read Xlsx file using fgetscsv?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have been trying to read the Xlsx file using fgetcsv concept. Its working for csv, but not for xlsx file

Thing is , its reading the file as like

```
Array
(
    [0] => S����b��wIp� �[�������׀�4�c�W�s�c3�Y�i����Ѐ�& �g���ńA�8���'qt��]�%]>XC�<=�_���G%�����*
)
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

and this is my code,

```
$file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
if($file){
   fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",");
    while (($example = fgetcsv($file, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE){
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($exampe); 
    }
}
```

I don't want to use PHPEXCEL library file to read xlsx file, How could I solve above issue.

Comment: `fgetcsv()` is used for reading CSV files (plain text, comma-separated values). XLSX files are ZIP-archives containing XML files. So no, you cannot use `fgetcsv()` on XLSX files.

Comment: You cannot "solve" the issue since it is not an issue. You are using the wrong tool for the task at hand.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, arkaschaThen Which method should I use ? . can you suggest me something

Comment: http://webexplorar.com/read-excel-file-and-save-details-to-database-using-php/

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself: use phpexcel or some other library to read the file. Or extract the main document's XML file from the archive and parse it yourself.

Comment: You can use other than phpexcel, like this:  https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Comment: okay thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

fgetcsv function is used to read the CSV files only you can't use this for XLS files.